# Is there a magic get longest line length feature in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have simple ascii text file like this:

```
Madonna is a celebrity
No she's not she's a serious artist
Did you see her book or the movie Truth or Dare
Argument closed
```

I need a method to get the length of the longest line. In this example the answer would be 47.

I can use `StreamReader` and open the file and read each line but it seems that there should an easier way.

Is there a simple to way solve this problem?

Comment: No, there is nothing "magic" about C#.  Famous quote: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."  If you want to be a developer, you have to stop considering technology to advanced for you to grasp, and try to actually understand it.

Comment: *"I can use StreamReader and open the file and read each line but it seems that there should an easier way."* - Easier for whom?  The machine has to do the same amount of work regardless, and would hardly call declaring a variable, opening a file, and keeping track of the longest line "difficult".

Comment: I do believe you are taking life a little too seriously. Don’t forget that none of us are going to make it out alive.

Comment: @Ed S. True I'm just trying understand the more time friendly way to do things.

Comment: I don't think typing a few extra characters is a bottleneck in your work... not that I don't appreciate nice syntactical shortcuts when available.

Comment: If you want the more "time friendly" way, you have to specify whether you mean development time or execution time. There are simpler ways, so they would cut your development time, but there are no reasonably simple way to cut the execution time from the solution using a StreamReader.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this nicely with `File.ReadLines`, which has the advantage that it does not read the entire file into memory. As it returns `IEnumerable<string>` you can use Linq on the return value, leading to this rather nice one liner.

```
File.ReadLines(fileName).Max(line => line.Length)
```

Comment: @codingguy3000 Just to be clear, this is doing exactly what you wanted an "easier way" to replace; it just looks prettier. Not that that's a bad thing.